# Cant unlock file (Errcode: 11) on my new tables

Tags: mysql, innodb, errors

I get the following error on my MySQL database

```
Cant unlock file (Errcode: 11)
```

But this error only happens when I try to access my new table I created below has two tables 1st I created recently and the second was already created when I got the database to update it
How I'm remove the errors?

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_produtos` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nome` varchar(140) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Descricao` text,
  `FotoDestaque` varchar(190) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FK_Categoria` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FK_SubCategoria` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Count` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `Valor` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Propriedades` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0,1',
  `FotoCapa` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `tbl_admin_logs` (
  `RegistroID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UsuarioID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `UsuarioNome` varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Modulo` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Registro` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `IProtocol` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RegistroID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=383 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT @@VERSION = 5.1.39-community
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%locking%'= 
Variable_name: skip_external_locking Value: OFF
```

Comment: Please include the output from `SELECT @@VERSION;` and `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%locking%';` and mention your server's operating system.

Comment: Please post your `my.cnf` (or `my.ini` if using Windows) in the question.

Comment: I just remove group by from query this:

`SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tbl_classificados p
        INNER JOIN
    tbl_class_cats c
WHERE
    ((p.Nome LIKE '%b%')
        OR (p.Descricao LIKE '%b%')
        OR (c.Nome LIKE '%b%'))
GROUP BY (p.ID); 
`

And don't have error anymore... but why this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion would be that you are either using `external_locking` or you have character set issues.

It might center around the following bugs

- [Error 11 - can't unlock file when using external_locking](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=59663)
- [Inconsistent use of column alias In ORDER BY clause that specified collation](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=59449)

I would suggest upgrading to MySQL 5.6 as this situation is consistent with MySQL 5.1.

Comment: So, usually this error happen with MySQL 5.1? Thanks very much!